# how to solve npm install command

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

i want to learn node js and my boss send me this project but its show error. how to solve this type of problem when i enter npm install this command is show below error...i already installed visual studio 2015

```
gyp ERR! stack operable program or batch file.
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack Can't find "msbuild.exe". Do you have Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2008+ installed?
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:134:25
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin
\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Addi\HeavyMetalServer\node_modules\iltorb
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `npm install` command fails during installing `node-gyp` module. `node-gyp` module gives a lot of problems when installing on windows. You can run this command to install its dependencies first - `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` . This command is given on their [github page](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp).

Answer (score 0):

For windows users:

Try running the `npm install` command from **Powershell** with administrative rights

This is one of the many workarounds